# Apache syntax error

Tags: apache, virtualhost

Using the below apache configuration in WAMP, I'm unable to boot up apache due to the error: `Syntax error on line 42 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:     .`

I've verified the path exists... what am I missing?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:\\wamp\\www\\mysite\\live"
    ServerName api.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    DocumentRoot "g:\\mysite\\live" //SYNTAX ERROR
    ServerName mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

In addition to that error, I also get another error: `DocumentRoot must be a directory     .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite G: being a mapped drive, WAMP didn't like it and wouldn't start when I used it.  Using the network path that virtual provided (`\\VBOXSVR\www`) has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is G: an unity connected?
Maybe Apache can't find it launching the syntax error.

Comment: I'm running Windows virtually and G: is a drive mapped via VirtualBox.  I'm able to navigate to that path and create/edit files there.